# Fetch the first record with a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I have a `User` model and a `Deposit` model.

One user `has_many :deposits` and one deposit `belongs_to :user`.

Now, deposits table has `user_id` as the foreign key.
Now how can I identify that a particular deposit is the first time deposit of a particular user?

Actually I need to write an instance method in Deposit model to identify this.

Please help me to sort this out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check that deposit is the only one existing deposit for now:

```
def only_one?
  user.deposits.count == 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily identify with `created_at` attribute.

ex.

```
user.deposits.order(:created_at).first
```

Hope it's help you

Comment: maybe checking also if user has any deposit : `if @user.deposits.any? then ...`

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the first deposit for a user:

```
class User
  def first_deposit
    deposits.order(created_at: :desc).first
  end
end
```

To check if a deposit is the first for a particular user:

```
class Deposit
  def first?
    self.class.where(user: user).order(created_at: :desc).first == self
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
class Deposit < ApplicationRecord

  def self.get_first_deposit(user)
    where(user_id: user.id).order(:created_at).first
  end 


end
```

And `Deposit.get_first_deposit(user)` will return first record.

Comment: As asked in question, it should be an instance method.